# Is there a word or phrase to describe someone sitting with their legs tucked?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a word or phrase (would prefer word) to describe someone sitting with their legs tucked. I'm not sure if this makes sense, but what I'm attempting to convey is that they are not outstretched but rather, sort of in an X position. (your legs are not under you.)

I'll give you an example to make it easier to comprehend.
Envisage you had to eat with a handful of people from one large plate(a basin), you would all have to encircle this basin in order to eat, so you would all have to readjust the way you sit.. and that is what I'm alluding to.. 'the X position'.. more or less crossed.

The reason I ask is, I was watching sport news the other day, and they said 'Chelsea are sitting comfortably at the top'. In my language, we would say they sat (in that X position) which would imply to comfort and control.

I hope I made sense..
Thank you 
(ah, It just came to mind, the way you sit if you would mediate maybe?)

Answer (score 5):

It is called sitting ***cross-legged***.

[image]

<sub><sup>Image source: http://yevgeniawatts.com/blog/child-on-the-beach-watercolor-step-by-step</sup></sub>

---

Also, there are other names of it:

- Criss-cross applesauce (childish, US)
- tailor style / tailor-fashion (in several European languages)
- Indian style (in English - from the way how Native American Indians sat, or from the Indian lotus position)
- Lotus position (in meditation)
- Turkish style (in many European languages)
- *Agura* (in Japanese - 胡座 The sitting style of non-Han ethnics (particularly Turks, Mongols and other Central Asians.))
- *Sukhasana* (in yoga)

Comment: I think it's the perfect answer. See [**Google images**](https://www.google.com/search?q=cross-legged.&client=firefox-a&hs=w0g&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=rcs&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=doZcVPiFJ4XaarW9gMgM&ved=0CDgQsAQ&biw=1366&bih=619). The only thing I might add is that you also *cross your legs* when you're sitting on a chair, but that's not the same as being *crossed-legged*.

Comment: The names in this answer may or may not be synonyms. For example, in the past I have heard the "Turkish style" being referred to what is depicted in the image, while "lotus pose" to a more strict posture, with one's both feet placed tightly on top of thighs (yes, it's possible to sit like this :) ).

Answer (score 1):

It's also referred to as sitting like a pretzel or sitting pretzel-style.

Comment: Cross Legged is of course how the position in picture above is commonly  defined. But this is something new I learnt today.